# Default browser

Tags: android, browser, settings, account

I'm using different browsers on my computer - to separate personal stuff with professional staff. Like Google login, for example, where I have my personal Google Cloud and Google Dev, and my company dev login, where I have company's Cloud and Dev account.
I did Log In of my company's account in Android Studio. But when I clicked on "Open Google Play Console" Android Studio opened a default browser where my personal stuff is. So I definitely went to Google to figure out how to change this behavior and surprisingly didn't find nothing about this - all links was about default browser on android device or in android application.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your objective is to contribute an answer, you are welcome to ask a question and then answer it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out it by myself :-) 
- Settings->Tools->Web Browsers 
- Move a required browser to 1st place of the list 
- At the bottom of the window change "Default Browser":"System default" to "First listed"
Maybe it can help to someone else...